# How to suppress the INFO and WARNING debugging information with Drool application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

After I ran Drools as a java application in Eclipse ,the console displayed:

```
......

INFO: Found kmodule: file:/D:/eworkspace/DroolsBasicsMavenWay/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml

Jun 06, 2018 5:19:54 PM org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject getPomPropertiesFromFileSystem

WARNING: Unable to find pom.properties in /D:/eworkspace/DroolsBasicsMavenWay/target/classes
Jun 06, 2018 5:19:54 PM org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject 

......

Drools 6.2.0.Final, topic level is null

Drools 6.2.0.Final, topic level is null

Drools 6.2.0.Final, topic level is Beginner
```

My question is how to remove the the `INFO` and `WARNING` debugging information with Drool application in Eclipse and I only want the last three lines.

Sorry,I am new to Drools, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to add log4j.xml or logging.properties in application classpath and set log level to OFF. Give a try with this approach.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I tried this approach by using log4j.properties in the root directory of my project,but it did not work. I think some third party's configuration file block my file from taking effect.

Comment: Try adding file in web-INF/classes directory if you have web application.

Comment: Thank you. It is not a web application. It is very kind of you to reply to my question.